# How to send paypal information to firebase swift code?

Tags: swift, firebase, paypal, swift4, paypal-sandbox

I want to access to the information that I have to save for legal after user pay by using PayPal. Here is the code when user select to pay by PayPal, but how can I fetch the information that PayPal give after user complete the payment. And how can I send them to firebase?

```
    
    @IBAction func btnPaypal(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        let payPalDriver = BTPayPalDriver(apiClient: braintreeClient)
            payPalDriver.viewControllerPresentingDelegate = self
            payPalDriver.appSwitchDelegate = self // Optional
               
               
        // Specify the transaction amount here. "2.32" is used in this example.
        let request = BTPayPalRequest(amount: lblSubtotal.text!)
            request.currencyCode = "USD" // Optional; see BTPayPalRequest.h for more options

            payPalDriver.requestOneTimePayment(request) { (tokenizedPayPalAccount, error) in
                if let tokenizedPayPalAccount = tokenizedPayPalAccount {
                   print("Got a nonce: \(tokenizedPayPalAccount.nonce)")

        // Access additional information
                    print("------------ paypal receipt -------------")
                    self.payPal = true
                let email = tokenizedPayPalAccount.email
                    debugPrint(email!)
                let firstName = tokenizedPayPalAccount.firstName
                    debugPrint(firstName!)
                let lastName = tokenizedPayPalAccount.lastName
                    debugPrint(lastName!)
                let phone = tokenizedPayPalAccount.phone
                    debugPrint(phone as Any)
                    
        // ....
                    let postalAddress = tokenizedPayPalAccount.billingAddress
                    // Access the properties of the address
                    debugPrint(postalAddress as Any)
                    let streetAddress = postalAddress?.streetAddress
                    debugPrint(streetAddress as Any)
                    let extendedAddress = postalAddress?.extendedAddress
                    debugPrint(extendedAddress as Any)
                    let locality = postalAddress?.locality
                    debugPrint(locality as Any)
                    let countryCodeAlpha2 = postalAddress?.countryCodeAlpha2
                    debugPrint(countryCodeAlpha2 as Any)
                    let postalCode = postalAddress?.postalCode
                    debugPrint(postalCode as Any)
                    let region = postalAddress?.region
                    debugPrint(region as Any)
                    

        // See BTPostalAddress.h for details
//                let billingAddress = tokenizedPayPalAccount.billingAddress
//                    debugPrint(billingAddress as Any)
                let shippingAddress = tokenizedPayPalAccount.shippingAddress
                    debugPrint(shippingAddress!)
                    
                    
                    for obj in self.arrayCart {
                          let invoiceID = self.ref.childByAutoId().key
                          let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

                          let invoice = [
                              "invoiceID" : invoiceID,
                              "buyerID" : userID,
                             
                              "payPal info" : ["payPal email" : email,
                                               "first name" : firstName,
                                               "last name" : lastName,
                                               "phone" : phone,
                                               "postalAddress" : postalAddress,
                                               "streetAddress" : streetAddress,
                                               "extendedAddress" : extendedAddress,
                                               "locality" : locality,
                                               "countryCodeAlpha2" : countryCodeAlpha2,
                                               "postalCode" : postalCode,
                                               "region" : region,
                                               "shippingAddress" : shippingAddress]
                              

                              
                              ] as [String : Any]
                          self.ref.child("invoice").child(invoiceID!).setValue(invoice)
                    
                    }
                    
                    
                    
                    
                 print("------------ paypal receipt end -------------")
                    } else if let error = error {
                    // Handle error here...
                    print("error -------- \(error)")
                    } else {
                    // Buyer canceled payment approval
                   // alert
    }
```

**Error:**

'InvalidFirebaseData', reason: '(setValue:) Cannot store object of type BTPostalAddress at payPal info.shippingAddress. Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArray.'

Answer (score 0):

The error messsage is pretty clear; you're attempting to store an object in Firebase Realtime Database that's not an object Firebase accepts.

Here's the object you're attempting to store

```
let shippingAddress = tokenizedPayPalAccount.shippingAddress
```

and Firebase only supports NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArray. See [Basic Write Operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#basic_write) for more info.

To fix it, you're going to need to deconstruct that object into primitive values, probably easiest to cast all of it's properties to strings and store that in a child node

```
payPal info
   payPal email: "some email"
   first name: "some first name"
   shippingAddressWithChildData:
      streetAddress: "some street address" //from the `tokenizedPayPalAccount.billingAddress` object
      extended: "some additional street address info"
```

If you really need to store that particular object, Firebase does support NSData so you could cast the whole thing to an NSData object and store that but I would not suggest that path.